# CentOS /sbin/dump to FTP

Tags: linux, backup, ftp, dump

I want to do full backup of my cloud image to my FTP server by using this command:

```
/sbin/dump -0uan -f - / | gzip -9
```

How do I send this to FTP server just by adding `| ftp ...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using curl:

```
... | curl -u User:Pass ftp://ftpserver/Folder/filename -T -
```

Found this at http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-44719.html

It seems you can also "invoke" a pipe from the ftp client itself, once you're logged in:

```
put "| command" myfile.dmp
```

Comment: I just started the first solution you mentioned. I will keep you posted.